# FactoryGirl with Refile gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, refile

I choose refile gem to handle file uploads in my application. I have some trouble with use it with FactoryGirl.
In my factory I have something like that:

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Company #{n}" }
    logo_id { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.to_s + "/spec/fixtures/images/1x1.gif") }
  end
end
```

When I run some feature specs it returns me the following error:

```
  5) Company destroying destroys company
     Failure/Error: visit companies_path
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Refile::InvalidID
```

EDIT:
This error is caused by this line in my view template:

```
  %td= image_tag attachment_url(company, :logo, :fill, 50, 50)
```

Comment: Have you tried just using the factory in a standalone spec? It's a quite high level error that you've posted...

Comment: And please post the code for the target class of the factory.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set the logo id manually. Try something like this. And also, to speed up your tests, use something lightweight instead of a real file, like `StringIO`.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Company #{n}" }

    logo {
      StringIO.new('hello')
    }
  end
end
```